# Should the table name "user" be used in a Symfony project?

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine

I know this sounds like an "opinion" question, but I don't think it is.

Normally, I would consider not using "user" as a table name as it is a [reserved word](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/sql-keywords-appendix.html), and I would rather not bother having to deal with it when I write native SQL queries.

But I am not writing native SQL queries, but am having Symfony and the Doctrine ORM perform all the queries.  And when I execute `php bin/console make:user`, Symfony prompts me to select the class name `User` which results with `user` as the table name.  Furthermore, most of the tutorials I have read also use the name user.  If using the name user is what is most common for other developers, I would rather stay consistent.

Most of the time, I don't have any issues, but every now and then, Doctrine crashes because it is querying the Postgres internal `user` table and not `public.user`.  As a workaround, I tried adding  `* @ORM\Table(schema="public")` to the User entity, but then when making migrations, it tries to duplicate the record resulting in errors.  Maybe Symfony/Doctrine needs to be configured somewhere as using the public schema?

Thanks

Comment: Are you perhaps mixing up the table name with column name?  make:user certainly does not prompt you for a property (aka column) named user.  In any event, I always use plurals for table names so 'users' avoids any problems.

Comment: @Cerad  Yes, sorry, silly mistake.  Just realized I had done so came back to change it but wasn't quick enough.  I've gone back and forth with plural or singular table names as well as camel or snake and standardized on singular snake for better or worse. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Since my question was "Should the table name “user” be used in a Symfony project?", the following doesn't answer the question, but I am still posting it should it be helpful for others.  Perhaps I will change the title to "How to use the table name “user” in a Doctrine project?", but not sure whether doing so is kosher.

I've since discovered other's experiencing issues resulting from this topic:

- https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/1222
- https://github.com/symfony/maker-bundle/pull/545

Also found the following at [doctrine-adding-mapping](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#doctrine-adding-mapping):

> Be careful not to use reserved SQL keywords as your table or column
> names (e.g. GROUP or USER). See Doctrine’s Reserved SQL keywords
> documentation for details on how to escape these. Or, change the table
> name with @ORM\Table(name="groups") above the class or configure the
> column name with the name="group_name" option.

Which directed me to [quoting-reserved-words](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#quoting-reserved-words) which directed me to escape the name using ticks.

```
  * @ORM\Table(name="`user`")
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no table `user` in PostgreSQL.

Tutorials that use `user` as a table name are not trustworthy. However, if you consistently use double quotes, there should be no problem. Since you claim to have problems with native queries, you might have forgotten that occasionally.

One possible source of confusion is that there is a *function* named `user` in PostgreSQL. So if you use `user` in a context where a function is possible, you'll get a function call. If you use it with schema qualification, you will get an error that there is no such object. Otherwise, you will get a syntax error:

```
test=> SELECT user;
  user   
---------
 laurenz
(1 row)

test=> SELECT * FROM user;
  user   
---------
 laurenz
(1 row)

test=> TABLE user;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "user"
LINE 1: TABLE user;
              ^
test=> SELECT * FROM public.user;
ERROR:  relation "public.user" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM public.user;
                      ^
```

Comment: Thank you Laurenz,  Ah ha, user is a function!  If I (or Doctrine) tries to execute `SELECT id FROM user;`, would get an error, but `SELECT id FROM public.user` would execute as desired.  No, I was having no problems with native queries but just need to remember to include `public.`, double quote camel case names such as `SELECT some_column AS "someColumn"`, etc.  Appreciate your response!